Keywords in lstlisting are not highlighted sometimes
As a follow up of lstlistings package: Replacing a character I don't understand why sometimes the keywords are highlighted and sometimes not
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Use Latin Modern high-quality fonts
\usepackage{lmodern}

% For colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

% For listings
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,% Enable UTF8 accentuated characters
  upquote=true,% Straight quotes in code
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},% We cannot use '*' to make keywords appear in upper case
  commentstyle=\color{purple},%
}
\lstdefinelanguage{mySQL}{%
  language=SQL,
  alsoletter={&,\_},
  morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{--},%
  morecomment=[s][commentstyle]{/*}{*/},%
  morekeywords={ALWAYS,BIGINT,BOOLEAN,COPY,COSTS,EPOCH,EXPLAIN,
    FILTER,FLOAT,FOR,FUNCTION,GENERATED,GROUPING,HASH,IF,IS,LAG,LATERAL,
    LEAD,LIST,MODE,MODULUS,NTILE,OF,OFF,ON,OVER,PARALLEL,PARTITION,
    PRECEDING,RANGE,RANK,REFERENCES,REMAINDER,ROW_NUMBER,SETS,SYSTEM,
    TABLESAMPLE,TEXT,TIMESTAMPTZ,TO,UNBOUNDED,UNSAFE,WITH,WITHIN,WITHOUT},
  }
% To disable the replacement of hyphen and asterisk
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{\lst@ttfamily{*{}}{*}}
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-}}
  \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

I don't understand why text or integer are only highlighted sometimes, why float or KEY are not highlighted. 

\begin{lstlisting}[language=mySQL]
Vehicles(VehicleId integer PRIMARY KEY, Licence text, VehicleType text, Model text)
Licences(LicenceId integer PRIMARY KEY, Licence text, VehicleId integer)
Municipalities(MunicipalityId integer PRIMARY KEY, MunicipalityName text,
Population integer, PercPop float, PopDensityKm2 integer, NoEnterp integer,
PercEnterp float, MunicipalityGeo geometry)
Trips(TripId integer PRIMARY KEY, VehicleId integer, StartDate date, SeqNo integer,
Trip tgeompoint, Trajectory geometry)
Instants(InstantId integer PRIMARY KEY, Instant timestamptz)
Periods(PeriodId integer PRIMARY KEY, Period tstzspan)
Points(PointId integer PRIMARY KEY, Geom geometry(Point))
Regions(RegionId integer PRIMARY KEY, Geom geometry(Polygon))
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

The result is as follows


You've made , a letter. So in “PopDensityKm2 integer,” the word is not “integer” but “integer,” and because “integer,” is not the lowercase form of INTEGER it is not highlighted. I suggest to read the documentation of alsoletter in the listings user manual carefully. In general, I think it is advisable not to simply adopt solutions, but to study the documentation of the instructions, environments, options, etc. used in them in order to gain a deeper understanding of the solution.

BTW: Making & a letter is IMHO not the best idea. In SQL & is the bitwise and operator. It can also occur as part of the bitwise and equals &=.

With a little debugging you can see that the culprit is the line starting with alsoletter.
Since you refer to your previous question, you are not copying the syntax as suggested:
  alsoletter={&},
  alsoletter={\_},

With this change, I believe that syntax highlighting works fine. You probably need to add some more keywords to your list.

alsoletter={&\_} should also work. The culprit is the , only.
